# How to abstract `reg-sub` in reframe

Tags: clojurescript, re-frame

in my code ,there is duplication like this:

```
(reg-sub
 :hello-john
 (fn [ db [ _ say-hi ]
   (str (get-in db [ say-hi ]) "hello John")
 )

(reg-sub
 :hello-jack
 (fn [ db [ _ say-hi ]
   (str (get-in db [ say-hi ]) "hello Jack")
 )
```

this pattern is quite tedious and I try to factor out with following code in `sub.cljs`:

```
(for [ [x y]  [[:hello-john "hello John"] 
                [:hello-jack "hello Jack"]]  ]
 (reg-sub
   x
   (fn [ db [ _ say-hi ]
     (str (get-in db [ say-hi ]) y ))
)
```

But it desn't work as expect. Thanks for reading this appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not

```
(reg-sub
 :say-hello
 (fn [ db [ _ person say-hi ]
   (str (get-in db [ say-hi ]) "hello " person)
 )
```

Comment: thanks for discover the underlying question ! it solve my root question !

Answer (score 2):

Your second code block is missing the closing `"`.

Another thing is that `for` is lazy - it won't be evaluated by itself. Replace it with `doseq`.

Finally, a minor thing - don't use `(get-in db [say-hi])`, instead use `(get db say-hi)`. And if `say-hi` in your case is always a keyword, you can use `(say-hi db)`.